# How to change the tab of ttk.Notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have a `ttk.Notebook` and with a button I would like to switch to another tab.
How can I achieve this?

It looks that changing the tab state (`normal`, `disabled`, and `hidden`) will not solve my problem since I don't want to disable any tabs.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import ttk as ttk
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

root.config(width=300,height=220)

notebook=ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.place(x=0,y=0)

tabList=[]
i=0
while i<6:    
     tabList.append(tk.Frame(root))
     tabList[i].config(width=300,height=150,background='white')
     i+=1

i=0
while i<6: 
    notebook.add(tabList[i],text='tab'+str(i))
    i+=1

def fLoopTabs():
    i=0
    while i<6:
         notebook.select(i)
         time.sleep(2)
         #Here goes the Screenshot function
         i+=1

 button=ttk.Button(root,text='Loop',command=fLoopTabs)
 button.place(x=20,y=180)

 root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

see the following link:
[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html#ttk.Notebook)
if you see the select method that should do what you're after, so something like this:

```
notebook.select(tab_id)
```

where the tab id can take a number of forms (see section 24.2.5.3) but the most useful ones are an integer (i think this is the index similar to how lists use indexes) or the name of the tab you wish to switch to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Im trying to use it inside a loop so I can screenshot every open notebook tab. The select(i) doesnt work inside a loop. I already tried to use time.sleep(5) to check if all tabs are then open. Just the last one will open.

Comment: as you are usiong this in a loop can i ask how you are putting the user interface into its message loop? time.sleep is a blocking call, and without entering the message loop (mainloop) the interface will not update until the loop exits, assuming thats the case you could either put in a call to root.update before the sleep, or you could use threading

Comment: thanks for your help I updated the code in my question.

Comment: as i thought, you need to make the user interface respond to messages, the simplest way to do this for your current purpose would be to add a line "root.update()" between the notebook.select line and the time.sleep line